# Torsion Spring Moment Calculation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, spring

I'm trying to extend the idea of a translational spring to a rotational spring. Consider a spring that acts on all displacements of a body:
$$
\mathbf{F} = \begin{bmatrix} F_x \\ F_y \\ F_z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -k_x u_x \\ -k_y u_y \\ -k_z u_z \end{bmatrix}
$$
with $k_x$, $k_y$, $k_z$ the stiffness of the spring and $u$ the displacement in x,y, and z.

If you want to extend this to a rotational spring, the following parametrisation in terms of Euler angles can be made:
$$
\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix} M_x \\ M_y \\ M_z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -k_x \phi \\ -k_y \theta \\ -k_z \psi \end{bmatrix}
$$
with $\phi$, $\theta$, $\psi$ the angles over which is rotated in a ZYX Euler rotation sequence. Note $k_x$, $k_y$, $k_z$ are not necessarily the same as before.

However, this introduces some issues. If another rotation sequence is chosen, e.g. XYZ, to produce the same rotation, the angles, and hence the moment, will be different than before. For small angles the results will be roughly equal but I'm looking for a general method. Furthermore, if rotation sequence XYX is chosen, there will be no moment in the Z-direction at all. Some simple cases can be considered to show that the moments are not equivalent for different rotation sequences.

So what would be a correct way of implementing the moments generated by a rotational spring in an arbitrary orientation?

Comment: Have you got any example for such actual "rotational springs"?

Comment: I was just thinking about a simple torsion spring that obeys Hooke's law:
$$
M = -k\theta
$$

but then it acts around three axes. Or, three torsion springs that each act around a single axis.

Comment: But a torsion spring has one $k$, not different $k_x$, $k_y$, $k_z$!

Comment: Then would it matter if you'd use three torsion springs?

Comment: My question is more about the mathematical formulation than the actual implementation of such a spring. You can imagine it to be a virtual spring acting around three axes